# Remove spaces and change symbol with space

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file with thousands of lines. Line example is:

```
205.188.213.249:193.219. 43. 13:193.219. 62.126:   82   76:         12:       2868
193.219.168. 18:206.126.  6. 38: 62. 40.103.217:    4   82:         11:        701
193.219. 52.163:217. 44.206.181: 62. 40.103.217:   76   82:          9:        531
193.219. 74.113:195. 22.175.  2:193.219. 62.126:    0   76:         29:      10396
193.219. 32. 13:195. 34. 96.  3: 62. 40.103.217:    0   82:          1:        227
```

I need:
1) to remove blank spaces between IP adress numbers;
2) to change this symbol `:` to `space`

It should look like this:

```
205.188.213.249 193.219.43.13 193.219.62.126 82 76 12 2868
```

I am trying with this command: `tr -d ' ' | tr ':' ' ' myfile` but doesn't work.

Comment: It's not `tr -d ' ' | tr ':' ' ' file` it's `tr -d ' ' file | tr ':' ' '`. `|` is a pipe, the input must go to the first command. Alternatively you can `<file tr -d ' ' | tr ':' ' '`

Comment: Command not found

Comment: Please post the full error message. It's `bash: blabla: command not found`. Which command was not found?

Comment: There is my command: `fileName tr -d ' ' | tr ':' ' '` And there is error message: `fileName: line 2462: 193.219.169.108:208.254.: command not found`

Comment: It's not `fileName tr -d ' ' | tr ':' ' '` but `<fileName tr -d ' ' | tr ':' ' '` or `tr -d ' ' fileName | tr ':' ' '` .....

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested with provided sample and with GNU `awk`).

```
awk '{gsub(/:/," ");gsub(/\. +/,".");gsub(/ +/," ")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `gsub` for global substitution here. 1st globally substrituting colon with space then globally substituting DOT with space with a DOT. Finally globally substituting space(s) with single space. Then by mentioning `1` letting `awk` know to print edited/non-edited line.

`awk` works on method of regexp/condition then action. If any regexp/condition is TRUE then action mentioned next to it will be performed. In this case I have not mentioned any action so by default print of current line will happen.

About `gsub` from man entry of `awk`:

```
   gsub(r, s [, t])        For each substring matching the regular expression r in the string t, substitute the string s, and return the number of substitutions.  If t is not supplied, use $0.   An  &  in  the
                           replacement text is replaced with the text that was actually matched.  Use \& to get a literal &.  (This must be typed as "\\&"; see GAWK: Effective AWK Programming for a fuller dis-
                           cussion of the rules for &’s and backslashes in the replacement text of sub(), gsub(), and gensub().)
```

---

---

***EDIT1:*** Adding `sed` solution now(tested it in GNU `sed`).

```
sed -E 's/:/ /g;s/\. +/\./g;s/ +/ /g' Input_file
```

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas, your welcome. Keep learning and keep sharing on this GREAT site SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F: '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (split($i,tmp,".") == 4) gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",$i); else {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i);gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS,$i);}}1' myfile
```

Put as several lines and add explanation:

```
awk -F: '{                                             ## -F: assign : as separator
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                              ## iterate every field
        if (split($i,tmp,".") == 4) {                  ## If split with . yields four parts, then it is an ip.
            gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",$i);                 ## Remove every space in the IP field.
        } else {                                       ## otherwise it is not an IP
            gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i); ## replace the spaces at the beginning or ending of each fields. Equals trim in some languages.
            gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS,$i);               ## Replace multiple places between with one space.
        }                                              
    }                                                  ## Below 1 is to print line
}1' myfile
```

This will be more compatible, can deal with `TAB` too, and the position of the spaces are not limited.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
 perl -lpe 's/\.\s+(?=\d+)/./g;s/:/ /g; s/\s+/ /g ' input_file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat edgaras.txt
205.188.213.249:193.219. 43. 13:193.219. 62.126:   82   76:         12:       2868
193.219.168. 18:206.126.  6. 38: 62. 40.103.217:    4   82:         11:        701
193.219. 52.163:217. 44.206.181: 62. 40.103.217:   76   82:          9:        531
193.219. 74.113:195. 22.175.  2:193.219. 62.126:    0   76:         29:      10396
193.219. 32. 13:195. 34. 96.  3: 62. 40.103.217:    0   82:          1:        227

$ perl -lpe 's/\.\s+(?=\d+)/./g;s/:/ /g; s/\s+/ /g ' edgaras.txt
205.188.213.249 193.219.43.13 193.219.62.126 82 76 12 2868
193.219.168.18 206.126.6.38 62.40.103.217 4 82 11 701
193.219.52.163 217.44.206.181 62.40.103.217 76 82 9 531
193.219.74.113 195.22.175.2 193.219.62.126 0 76 29 10396
193.219.32.13 195.34.96.3 62.40.103.217 0 82 1 227

$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with sed :

```
sed '
  :A
    s/\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]\(.*\.[^\.]*\)/\1\2/
    tA
  s/:\?[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\|:/ /g
' infile
```